# Firebase returning undefinfed

Tags: firebase, promise, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I keep getting a response undefined with the return function. After a second the console.log displays the information. My guess is that the data is still being gathered and that the function is already returning. I thought it would be solved with a promise but it has not. What am I missing? why is my function returning without any data?

```
    TakenSpaces = 0
    let startDate = new Date(time)
    startDate.setHours(0)
    startDate.setMinutes(0)
    let endDate = new Date(startDate)
    endDate.setHours(24)
    data = []
    const reservations = db.collection('organisation').doc('Amigos').collection('reservations')
    .where('start', '>=', startDate)
    .where('start', '<=', endDate).get()
    console.log('promse made')
    reservations.then((docs) => {
      // console.log(docs.data())
      // return docs.data()
      // const promises = []
      docs.forEach((doc) => {
        data.push(doc.id)
      })
      // console.log(data)
      // console.log('DONE TESTING')
      return data
        // return Promise.all(promises)
    })
    .then((test) => { console.log(test); return test })
  // for (const reservation of reservations) {
  //   console.log(reservation)
  // }
    // .then((docs) => {
    //   // for (const doc of docs) {
    //   //   console.log(doc.id)
    //   // }
    //   docs.forEach((doc) => {
    //     if (doc.data().people){
    //       const people = doc.data().people
    //       TakenSpaces = TakenSpaces + people
    //     }
    //     // console.log(doc.data().people)
    //   });
    //   return TakenSpaces
    // })
  // return TakenSpaces
}
```

```
  const t = getTakenCapacity(time)
  console.log(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works know. But If anyone knows if the function can only return when everything is finished and not have to return a promise function.

```
function getTakenCapacity (time) {
    TakenSpaces = 0
    let startDate = new Date(time)
    startDate.setHours(0)
    startDate.setMinutes(0)
    let endDate = new Date(startDate)
    endDate.setHours(24)
    data = []
    const reservations = db.collection('organisation').doc('Amigos').collection('reservations')
    .where('start', '>=', startDate)
    .where('start', '<=', endDate).get()
    return reservations.then((docs) => {
      // console.log(docs.data())
      // return docs.data()
      // const promises = []
      var dd = new Array
      docs.forEach((doc) => {
        data.push([[time], doc.data().people])
      })
      // console.log(data)
      // console.log('DONE TESTING')
      return data
        // return Promise.all(promises)
    })
```

```
  getTakenCapacity(time).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result) // "Some User token"
  })
```

Comment: I would say go for [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await) stuff. like `function async getTakenCapacity ..` and inside `const reservations = await db.collection(..`. The function will wait until promise is resolved and reservations will be assigned its result. Then you can proceed synchronously, manipulate the results and return what you need.